# Detecting dead proxies

Tags: c#, proxy

Is it possible to detect which proxy is active which is dead?
using c# and a combo box containing list of proxies with port number is there any way we take every proxy one by one and determine as if it was dead or active?

```
 Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey registry = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
                    registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
                    registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", comboBox1.Text)
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx with sites as google and facebook [They will almost never fail xD] so if you get timeouts or null/wrong/unexpected data [Verify this with an HTML parser as [this](http://www.justagile.com/linq-to-html.aspx) or [this](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)], you know the proxy is down/not working, also you can switch the proxy of your HttpWebRequest Instance and re-issue the command. hope it helps ;)